# removing file extension from anywhere in the the url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following lines in my htaccess file which makes http://mydomain.com/pages work as if it were http://mydomain.com/pages.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

HOWEVER

my urls my look like this http://mydomain.com/pages/1234/SOMETHING OR http://mydomain.com/pages/something/1/something else etc.  ho do i remove the extension from pages not knowing what the rest of the length of my url will look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove your rule and have this line on top of your .htaccess to extension-less access to you pages anywhere on your site:

```
Options +MultiViews
```